# Align text to center in System.Drawing.RectangleF

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to create a captcha image. I am generating a random string and rotating the text with a random angle and trying to create a byte array. Below is my code snippet:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Images\BackGround.jpg");
RectangleF myRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
objGraphics.DrawImage(img, myRect);


Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix();
int i = 0;

StringFormat formatter = new StringFormat();
formatter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

for (i = 0; i <= myString.Length - 1; i++)
{
    myMatrix.Reset();
    int charLenght = myString.Length;
    float x = width / (charLenght + 1) * i;
    float y = height / 30F;

    myMatrix.RotateAt(oRandom.Next(-40, 40), new PointF(x, y));
    objGraphics.Transform = myMatrix;

    objGraphics.DrawString(myString.Substring(i, 1), MyFont, MyFontEmSizes,       MyFontStyles,
                           MySolidBrush, x, Math.Max(width, height) / 50, formatter );

    objGraphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

Every thing is working fine, except that, the first character in my final image on the web page is crossing my left border of the rectangle. How can I align my text to the center of the rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: The first character will have x = 0.  Rotating it around that point will of course make it cross the border.  You'll need to add padding on the left and right.

Comment: I tired finding on how to add padding to my rectangle object. I didn't had luck init. can you please provide me with a line of code for padding?

Comment: float x = padding + i * (width - 2 * padding) / (charLenght + 1);